# Sorting and restructuring json objects w/ underscore

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

I'm struggling with ordering JavaScript objects. Here is the part of data that I have to  sort.

I would like to group each object by `ParentMemberCode` and then order them by `Order`.

```
{
    "MemberCode": "B1G",
    "ParentMemberCode": "B1_GA",
    "MemberName": "Gross value added at basic prices, total activity",
    "Order": 1
},
{
    "MemberCode": "P119",
    "ParentMemberCode": "B1_GA",
    "MemberName": "Financial Intermediation Services Indirectly Measured (FISIM)",
    "Order": 2
},
{
    "MemberCode": "B1G_P119",
    "ParentMemberCode": "B1_GA",
    "MemberName": "Gross value added at basic prices, excluding FISIM",
    "Order": 3
},
{
    "MemberCode": "D21_D31",
    "ParentMemberCode": "B1_GA",
    "MemberName": "Taxes less subsidies on products",
    "Order": 4
},
{
    "MemberCode": "B1_GE",
    "ParentMemberCode": "GDP",
    "MemberName": "Gross domestic product - expenditure approach",
    "Order": 1
},
{
    "MemberCode": "GDP",
    "ParentMemberCode": "GDP",
    "MemberName": "Gross domestic product",
    "Order": 1
},
{
    "MemberCode": "B1_GI",
    "ParentMemberCode": "GDP",
    "MemberName": "Gross domestic product - income approach",
    "Order": 2
},
{
    "MemberCode": "B1_GA",
    "ParentMemberCode": "GDP",
    "MemberName": "Gross domestic product at market prices - output approach",
    "Order": 3
}
```

I want to restructure and sort the data like this:

```
{
    "MemberCode": "GDP",
    "ParentMemberCode": "GDP",
    "MemberName": "Gross domestic product",
    "Order": 1
}

{
    "MemberCode": "B1_GE",
    "ParentMemberCode": "GDP",
    "MemberName": "Gross domestic product - expenditure approach",
    "Order": 1
},
,
{
    "MemberCode": "B1_GI",
    "ParentMemberCode": "GDP",
    "MemberName": "Gross domestic product - income approach",
    "Order": 2
},
{
    "MemberCode": "B1_GA",
    "ParentMemberCode": "GDP",
    "MemberName": "Gross domestic product at market prices - output approach",
    "Order": 3,
    [
        {
            "MemberCode": "B1G",
            "ParentMemberCode": "B1_GA",
            "MemberName": "Gross value added at basic prices, total activity",
            "Order": 1
        },
        {
            "MemberCode": "P119",
            "ParentMemberCode": "B1_GA",
            "MemberName": "Financial Intermediation Services Indirectly Measured (FISIM)",
            "Order": 2
        },
        {
            "MemberCode": "B1G_P119",
            "ParentMemberCode": "B1_GA",
            "MemberName": "Gross value added at basic prices, excluding FISIM",
            "Order": 3
        },
        {
            "MemberCode": "D21_D31",
            "ParentMemberCode": "B1_GA",
            "MemberName": "Taxes less subsidies on products",
            "Order": 4
        },
    ]
}
```

It's really complex to me so I need your help.
Do you have any ideas about that?

Please don't limit your idea w/ underscore.js.

Comment: @JustAnil Thanks for making my idea clear.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something similar recently, I used Underscore.nest (https://github.com/iros/underscore.nest), which is a neat little js plugin where you can specify a field to fold the data into, You can then use underscore.sort to sort the generated tree structure?

Comment: It looks like what I'm looking for. I'll try this one.

Answer (score 1):

I was about to say I don't see what the big problem is here.  But then I realize what you wanted is invalid.

You can't have an item in an object without a key.

```
{
    "MemberCode": "B1_GA",
    "ParentMemberCode": "GDP",
    "MemberName": "Gross domestic product at market prices - output approach",
    "Order": 3,
    [
        {
            "MemberCode": "B1G",
            "ParentMemberCode": "B1_GA",
            "MemberName": "Gross value added at basic prices, total activity",
            "Order": 1
        },
....
```

does not create a valid object.  you'd need a name for the property holding the array.

```
{
    "MemberCode": "B1_GA",
    "ParentMemberCode": "GDP",
    "MemberName": "Gross domestic product at market prices - output approach",
    "Order": 3,
    "Children": [
        {
            "MemberCode": "B1G",
            "ParentMemberCode": "B1_GA",
            "MemberName": "Gross value added at basic prices, total activity",
            "Order": 1
        },
....
```

As far as creating this, you only need to be able to iterate through your objects in the topmost array, looking up each `ParentMemberCode` by it's `MemberCode` (you might want to create another dictionary referring to each object by the `MemberCode` directly before you iterate through so that each lookup takes on average log(the number of items)), and add the child item to the parent's `Children` array (when you add the array is up to you), and then, maybe as you search or afterwards, filter out all the objects that have already been assigned a parent (that isn't themselves).

Comment: Thanks for commenting my mistake. I've should named the name of array like you did.